# Polars equivalent of pandas expression df.groupby['col1','col2']['col3'].sum().unstack()

Tags: python, dataframe, analytics, data-analysis, python-polars

```
pandasdf=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "fruits": ["banana", "banana", "apple", "apple", "banana"],
        "B": [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        "cars": ["beetle", "audi", "beetle", "beetle", "beetle"],
        "optional": [28, 300, None, 2, -30],
    }
)
pandasdf.groupby(["fruits","cars"])['B'].sum().unstack()
```

[image]

How can i create an equivalent truth table in polars?

Something like the below table into a truth table

```
df=pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "fruits": ["banana", "banana", "apple", "apple", "banana"],
        "B": [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        "cars": ["beetle", "audi", "beetle", "beetle", "beetle"],
        "optional": [28, 300, None, 2, -30],
    }
)
df.groupby(["fruits","cars"]).agg(pl.col('B').sum()) #->truthtable
```

The efficiency of the code is important as the dataset is too large (for using it with apriori algorithm)

The unstack function in polars is different, polars alterative for pd.crosstab would also work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you want tot do a `pivot`.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "fruits": ["banana", "banana", "apple", "apple", "banana"],
        "B": [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        "cars": ["beetle", "audi", "beetle", "beetle", "beetle"],
        "optional": [28, 300, None, 2, -30],
    }
)

df.pivot(values="B", index="cars", columns="fruits", aggregate_function=pl.element().sum())
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌────────┬────────┬───────┐
│ cars   ┆ banana ┆ apple │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64    ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ beetle ┆ 6      ┆ 5     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ audi   ┆ 4      ┆ null  │
└────────┴────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: I'm assuming it was edited because pivot's `aggregate_fn=` has been renamed to `aggregate_function=` (although they also changed `pl.element().sum()` to `"sum"` which wasn't needed)

Comment: This doesn't work as of version 0.20 (throws a `TypeError`). `aggregate_fn ` should be `aggregate_function`.